# Set up Prometheus with Docker Compose

Tags: docker-compose, yaml, prometheus

I am new to Prometheus and Docker Compose. I have a project structure with `docker-compose.yml` file that setup Prometheus and Grafana:
`/prometheus-grafana/prometheus/docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
prometheus:
image: prom/prometheus:v2.21.0
ports:
- 9000:9090
volumes:
- ./prometheus:/etc/prometheus
- prometheus-data:/prometheus
command: --web.enable-lifecycle --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml

grafana:
image: grafana/grafana:$GRAFANA_VERSION
environment:
GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER: $GRAFANA_ADMIN_USER
GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD: $GRAFANA_ADMIN_PASSWORD
ports:
- 3000:3000
volumes:
- grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana
depends_on:
- prometheus
networks:
- internal

networks:
internal:

volumes:
prometheus-data:
grafana-storage:
```

I just added more config in `/prometheus-grafana/prometheus/prometheus/prometheus.yml` like this, the part that I added is the last 3 lines:

```
global:
scrape_interval: 30s
scrape_timeout: 10s

rule_files:
- alert.yml

scrape_configs:
- job_name: services
metrics_path: /metrics
static_configs:
- targets:
- 'prometheus:9090'
- 'idonotexists:564'
- job_name: myapp
scrape_interval: 10s
static_configs:
- targets:
- localhost:2112
```

I started Prometheus by running: `docker-compose up -d`, I got to Prometheus on `http://localhost:9000/graph` but I don't see the new config I added to `prometheus.yml`, in `docker-compose.yml` file, there is a line:

```
command: --web.enable-lifecycle --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

Am I supposed to change this too refers to the path of my another `/prometheus-grafana/prometheus/prometheus/prometheus.yml` in my project instead of from `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml` as in reality, this file doesn't exist `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have prometheus configured with `--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml` it expects its config file to be at exact this position.

Since you have the the following mount points already configured:

```
volumes:
- ./prometheus:/etc/prometheus
- prometheus-data:/prometheus
```

you just need to put your config file into `./prometheus` and name it `prometheus.yml`

Comment: Thank you, in fact, I log into my docker container and check the prometheus.yml in there and it's the correct file. So, my prometheus works already.